# Using recursion to print numbers

Tags: java, recursion, printing

How would I use recursion to print the first parameter in the number base specified by the second parameter in the `printConvertedNumber` method

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NumberBaseConversion
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number,
        base;

    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a positive base 10 number: ");
      number = input.nextInt();
    } while (number <= 0);
    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a base (2, 4, or 8): ");
      base = input.nextInt();
    } while (base != 2 && base != 4 && base != 8);
    printConvertedNumber(number, base);
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void printConvertedNumber(int num, int base)
  {
    // Where i need to use recursion
  }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: How would you do it without recursion? First figure out the algorithm to obtain the correct digits (write the steps down on paper and try it out on few numbers by hand), then it should be apparent.

Comment: I don't think recursion is a good choice here.  Just use `Integer.toString(x, base)` and take the first digit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen While a valid point, it seems that's not the aim of this excercise. It could certainly be done and in a fairly trivial way. To me it appears as an excercise to learn recursion (and algorithms), probably a homework.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you a pseudo call flow that will do it for a base 10 number.

```
printConvertedNumber(1234, 10)
    printConvertedNumber(123, 10)
        printConvertedNumber(12, 10)
            printConvertedNumber(1, 10)
                print(1)
            print(2)
        print(3)
    print(4)
```

Each invocation optionally makes a recursive call, followed by a print statement that prints the *last* digit of the incoming number, in the given base.

Result: `1234` was printed.